# Excel performance issues and Issues Releasing Excel

Tags: c#, excel

1. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` (Visual Studio 2012) to populate my spreadsheet and it's painfully slow (2 minutes to insert 3000 rows x 25 columns).
2. Issues releasing Excel ... despite releasing the object, I keep seeing Excel in my list of processes, sometimes multiple times. (FYI: Multiple users will be creating spreadsheets at the same time, so I can't kill all Excel processes)
3. The spreadsheet I am loading has multiple tabs with calculations ... can that be slowing down my process? Prior to updating, I am setting `Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual`.

Here is my sample code:

```
Application AppExcel = null;
Workbook ExcelBook = null;
Worksheet ExcelSheet = null;

try
{
    string ExcelPath = @"c:\temp\test.xlsx";

    //-------------------------------------
    // create excel object
    //-------------------------------------
    AppExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    AppExcel.Visible = false;
    AppExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    AppExcel.ScreenUpdating = false;

    //-------------------------------------
    // open Excel Workbook
    //-------------------------------------
    ExcelBook = AppExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);
    ExcelBook.Activate();
    int WorksheetToUpdate = 1;


    AppExcel.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;

    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.Worksheets[WorksheetToUpdate];

    // test data
    for (int ExcelRow = 2; ExcelRow <= 3000; ExcelRow++)
    {                 
        ExcelSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 1] = "Client #1"
        ...
        ExcelSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 25] = "10020";

    }

    AppExcel.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic; 


    //-------------------------------------
    // save WorkBook
    //-------------------------------------                
    ExcelBook.Save();

    //-------------------------------------
    // release worksheet
    //------------------------------------- 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelSheet);

    //-------------------------------------
    // close WorkBook
    //-------------------------------------    
    ExcelBook.Close(true);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelBook);

    //-------------------------------------
    // quit Excel
    //-------------------------------------                
    AppExcel.Quit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(AppExcel);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    AppExcel = null;
    ExcelBook = null;
    ExcelSheet = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The performance problem in your code is related to the number of calls you are making into Excel from the CLR; each one of those calls is a trip across a COM boundary, and is very expensive.

Instead of doing this:

```
// test data
for (int ExcelRow = 2; ExcelRow <= 3000; ExcelRow++)
{                 
    ExcelSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 1] = "Client #1"
    ...
    ExcelSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 25] = "10020";

}
```

It would be far more efficient to create a range in the sheet, build the data set into an array and then pass that array to the range. For example:

```
 Excel.Range r = ExcelSheet.Range["B2", "B4"];
 object[,] workingValues = new object[3, 1];
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
      workingValues[i, 0] = i + 2;  // 2,3,4 
 }

 r.Value2 = workingValues;
```

you'll need to change the range to match what you're working with and the loop to populate your data, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: WONDEFUL!!!!!       Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   But I am still having issues disposing of Excel ... when I check the processes it's still out there.   Any ideas ?

Comment: It can be painful; You need to release each object in hierarchical order; i.e. release Range reference before release Sheet reference before Workbook reference before Excel Application instance. I'll update my answer with some code.

Comment: Actually, Sorceri has provided an answer to the disposing issue below... I'd be reproducing his code, basically.

Comment: stumbled across this today, and it sped up what I'm doing with an excel spreadsheet by a **HUGE** amount.  fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method for releasing the office objects such as th eone below. Then call it for each office object you create.  Also when you assign your workbook object you do not need to call the application object again

```
ExcelBook = AppExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);
```

should be

```
ExcelBook = AppExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);
```

release office objects

```
ReleaseOfficeObject(ExcelSheet);
ReleaseOfficeObject(ExcelBook);
ReleaseOfficeObject(AppExcel);


    private void ReleaseOfficeObject(object o)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```